# Rails Arrays and Mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have a User with one or more email addresses, and I don't want to create a new table for emails. The idea was to store email addresses as Array, but how do I implement this in the controller and the model?
This is the controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def update
@user =User.find(params[:id])

if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  redirect_to :action => 'show', :id => @user
```

Is it possible to check during update if the email parameter is already there or a new one and if it is new add it to an Array?
I don't know if I made myself clear, but thanks anyway for any answer you or suggestion you will provide!
By the way, I am using mysql and I can't switch to a different one!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can store it as a comma separated list.

or use [rails serialize](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class) to do the job

For example,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
    serialize :emails, Array 
end
```

would maintain the array format when retrieved as user.emails.
you can always validate whether an email is present in an array.

But my suggestion is to have a separate model. Future might hold new features like assigning primary and secondary emails and what not. then this design would not be so helpful

Comment: P.S - Any class type can be passed on to the serialize directive. Array, Hash, JSON another activerecord too possibly

Comment: Thank you very much! 
 I am actually using active_model_serializer to render  data as Json for an Ember Client.
Do you think I can do the same thing through active_model_serializer?
Thank you again for you answer!

Comment: From what I read about active_model_serializer from http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers, it seems to be more of a representational utility (convert ActiveRecord to json and hence create an API). but here, our goal is to store object in a serialized fashion. I think this will not serve the purpose. Its understandable to want to use one fix for all :) Been there!

P.S - rails serialize is part of rails already and so you don't have to feel like using unwanted extra gem or something. Its there for us developers to exploit.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend! You've been very helpful!
I will follow your suggestions and eventually I'll let you know the results!
Have a nice day!

Comment: This answer solves our problems, but how do we query array items. In this example (emails): assume we have ['email1@blah.com','email2@mail.com']. how do we query users that have 'email1@blah.com'? how do we query users that have 'blah.com' emails?