# How to query array column from mysql in Rails 5.2?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am using `gem rails~> 5.2` and `gem mysql2 >= 0.3.13, < 0.5`.

I have a model `Lawer`, which has an array column `lawer_filed` [sic].

```
# Model lawer.rb

serialize :lawer_field, Array
```

Then I created a `Lawer`, and I can get the `lawer_field` value as follows:

```
=> Lawer.first.lawer_field

=> ["2", "3", "5"]
```

Now, I want to find one `Lawer` with a query using `lawer_field`. I tried:

```
@lawer = Lawer.where("lawer_field && ARRAY[?]", "2")
```

which raised an error like this:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '['2']) LIMIT 11' at line 1: SELECT  `lawers`.* FROM `lawers` WHERE (lawer_field && ARRAY['2']) LIMIT 11)
```

There is a mistake in my SQL syntax, but I don't how to fix it. Can anyone help?

Comment: I am not sure whether i am right or wrong but "2" should be in array . Can you try this one `@lawer = Lawer.where("lawer_field && ARRAY[?]", ["2"])`  
`

Comment: I also try as your codes @Vishal, I got the error like this: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '['2']) LIMIT 11' at line 1: SELECT  `lawers`.* FROM `lawers` WHERE (lawer_field &&  ARRAY['2']) LIMIT 11)`, it does not work either.

Comment: Is `lawer_filed` playing any role here?

Comment: No role for `lawer_field`,@sawa.

Comment: `Lawer.where("lawer_field AND ARRAY[?]", "2")` have you tried this?

Comment: I had tried your codes,@Gabbar, it also returns syntax error like this:`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '['2']) LIMIT 11' at line 1: SELECT  `lawers`.* FROM `lawers` WHERE (lawer_field AND ARRAY['2']) LIMIT 11)`

Comment: @SylorHuang Checkout the given answer below and let me know if it's working?

Comment: @SylorHuang MySQL does not support arrays. You can either use a `LIKE` query or extract the array to a separate table using a `has_many` relation.

Comment: eh...@MarcinKołodziej , do you mean that MySQL can only save data with array, but do not support query from array column?

Comment: @SylorHuang it doesn't save array, you're saving varchar/text and ActiveRecord is unpacking that value. Check the type of your column in `db/schema.rb`.

Comment: Yes , I set the `lawer_field` type as `String`,the codes like this: `t.string "lawer_field"`. @MarcinKołodziej, I had used `LIKE` query, but it returns nil array. So now , one way to solution this problem is to build new table for lawer_field. Thanks so much.

Comment: @SylorHuang `LIKE` will work if you write it correctly, you must've made a mistake, but it still will be inefficient and won't be able to cover most cases. I'll add an answer which explains what's wrong as all the answers assume PostgreSQL right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL, unlike PostgreSQL, does not support arrays in database. Therefore you needed to add this line:

```
serialize :lawer_field, Array
```

This means that you have a `string` field in your database, but whenever ActiveRecord is unpacking results returned by the database, it maps them directly to an instance of Ruby Array. What this means is that your only option to filter the results in the database is with any MySQL string comparison functions, `LIKE`, etc.

Your options are to either use `LIKE` or perform some other [String functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) (which will not perform well as you will be unable to use indices) or build another table, add a `has_many` association to it and use MySQL the way it was supposed to be used. You could also, of course, migrate to PostgreSQL, but that seems to be the most extreme option.

**EDIT:** you could also consider using MySQL`s [JSON](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html), which has been added recently. That depends on your version of MySQL though.

Comment: I had tried `LIKE` function like this : `Lawer.all.where("lawer_field LIKE ? ","2")`, it returns nil array.What's wrong with the codes, and How to write correctly the codes? Could you teach me ? Thanks so much.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19105706/rails-4-like-query-activerecord-adds-quotes

Comment: That is great! Thanks a lot. It works. @Marcin Kołodziej. Next step , I will consider change MySQL to PostgreSQL.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't try this answer because I don't have any Rails project ready for testing, but I think the problem is in the syntax.

I think it should be something like this:

`Lawer.where("lawer_field IN (?)", "2")`

Comment: I had try as your code @Efesto, but I got the same error: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2') LIMIT 11' at line 1: SELECT  `lawers`.* FROM `lawers` WHERE (lawer_field IN '2') LIMIT 11)`, Thanks any way.

Comment: I edited the code because I think the brackets are necessary, maybe give it another shot now ;)

Comment: With the edited code, I didn't got syntax error, but it returns a nil array, the result is : ` => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []> `, this is for why? Thanks @Efesto.

Comment: I just checked and MYSQL doesn't seem to implement the array type, it could be useful for you to implement a serializable field for storing the array as in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685984/rails-arrays-and-mysql or directly to build another table.

Comment: Thanks any way, @Efesto. I had serializable the field in `Lawer.rb`, `serialize :lawer_field, Array`. Maybe I had to build another table for `lawer_field`.